# how to dismiss a UIView when tapped outside its bounds?

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiview

I have a View Controller that has a main view, inside that i have created a small drop down(a pop up menu) towards the right that is also a `UIView`. I have added a button that shows and dismisses this pop up menu view when tapped.

All is working fine.

But now I want it to dismiss the view when the user taps outside those bounds.
The current code is as follows

```
var vw =  UIView()

func popup(){
    vw = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 210, 20, 260, 320))
    vw.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    vw.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

    vw.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    vw.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    vw.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
    vw.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)
    let name: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, 0, 90, 30))
    name.text = testUserName
    name.font = UIFont(name: "Abc Lt", size: 20.0)
    let orgName: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, 35, 90, 30))
    orgName.text = "Abc Lt"
    name.font = UIFont(name: "V Lt", size: 25.0)
    let profileImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(137, 4, 35, 35))
    profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "profilepic.png")
    let dropUpButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(profileImageView.frame.origin.x + 42, 18, 15, 10))
    // dropUpButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdown.png"];
    dropUpButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "dropup.png"), forState: .Normal)
    dropUpButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(LandingPageViewController.hideView), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    vw.addSubview(name)
    vw.addSubview(orgName)
    vw.addSubview(profileImageView)
    vw.addSubview(dropUpButton)

    self.drawLine()
    let tableView: UITableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 70, vw.frame.size.width, vw.frame.size.height-40), style: .Plain)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    tableView.scrollEnabled = false
    vw.addSubview(tableView)

    self.navigationController!.view!.addSubview(vw)
}

//the function that displays and dismiss the pop up menu

func hideView() {
    vw.hidden = true
}
```

I have read some posts where one can use a tap gesture to find where it's tapped, and based on that using an `if`/`else` condition it can be solved but I am not sure.

Also you can check the image that I have uploaded for better understanding:

[image: want to dismiss this alert when touched outside its bounds]

Answer (score 1):

What you can really do is to take main superview full size same as your screen size. give clear background to it.Take a contentview same as you are doing now. Add a button similar size to super view and on click selector you can remove view from superview.

There are also alternative ways for doing this by identifying touch location. But It takes lots of effort.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: need more clarity, could some one throw some code here ?! Please suggest alternate ways.

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use tap gesture to do that 

add this code on main view:

let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleTap(_:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

and then

func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil)
    {
        hideView()
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I tried but it crashed. ViewController has no member `handleTap`,

Comment: its just a blank project.